# What does "default values" do in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have come across the following piece of T-SQL.  Can somebody explain what it does.

```
INSERT #numbers default VALUES
```

The temporary table #numbers was created a few lines before with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #numbers (num int identity primary key)
```

What does the "default values" bit do?

Comment: According to Microsoft: `Forces the new row to contain the default values defined for each column.` I guess in your case, you'll get get a row with num set to the next identity.

Comment: Yes, this will insert the next possible value. ie. Your table contains values like 1,2,3 then this will insert 4. Also have a look at [INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

Comment: OK thanks - strange use of it in my case then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I will never understand the need for the #numbers table, with just one column defined as identity, there is no other way to insert data into that table

```
INSERT #numbers default VALUES
```

will insert one row of data with the next `IDENTITY` value. The only alternate would be to use `IDENTITY INSERT ON`, which would be cumbersome in this case

Answer (score 0):

The DEFAULT constraint is used to insert a default value into a column.

The default value will be added to all new records, if no other value is specified.

In your case, you just have an identity column which does not really correspond to a column with a specified default value.